# Prove that for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, $a!b!$ divides $(a+b)!$.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, $a!b!$ divides $(a+b)!$.

This follows since $\binom{a+b}{a} = \dfrac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$, which is an integer.

Are there any other arguments besides this one to prove the result or do I need to elaborate on the one above?

Comment: Well,you could do a direct computation and rearrangement of terms from the definition. It'd be tedious,but it would get you there.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is fine and is the simplest one.

For another argument, this follows from Lagrange's theorem in group theory because $S_a \times S_b$ can be seen as a subgroup of $S_{a+b}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with group theory, and with binomials, but also with high school arithmetic, like so:

$$\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots a\cdot (a+1)\cdot (a+2)\cdots (a+b)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots a\cdot 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdots b}= \frac{(a+1)\cdot(a+2)\cdot(a+3)\cdots(a+b)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots b}$$

In the last equation, I can pair up each term in the numerator with one in the denumerator such that the result is an integer. Why? Because the terms in the numerator are $b$ consecutive integers, so by the pigeon hole principle there's at least one that's divisible by $b$, and another one divisible by $b-1$, and another one $\ldots$

Comment: I'm probably just being dim, but I don't see how you use the pigeon hole principle to get the desired conclusion here.

Comment: @RobArthan it's a bit of a leap, and maybe the pigeon hole principle isn't the right word for it. But here's a try: Of the $b$ consecutive integers compute them modulo $b$. There are at most $b$ different possible outcomes, and there are $b$ elements, and there are no duplicates, so there are exactly $b$ possible outcomes, so one of them is $0\mod b$, so one is divisible by $b$. By the same argument, at least one of these numbers is divisible by $b-1$, but unless $b-1=1$, these numbers are different. Not sure how to carry on for smaller divisors, to be honest.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to complete your line of argument either: it is true that any sequence of $b$ consecutive positive integers is divisible by $b!$ but I don't know of a proof along the lines you have in mind. (But, I may well just be being dim.)

Comment: @RobArthan No, you're right, it is much better to prove this using induction than to assert that it somehow follows from a loosely-defined pigeon hole principle. Personally, I give points for trying for the first part, "any sequence of $b$ consecutive numbers contains a number that divides $b$", but not more.

Answer (score -1):

$C(a,b)$ is $(a+b)!/(a!b!)$ Which means the number of ways to select $1,2,\dots,a$ from $1,2, \dots,a+b$ without permutation therefore it is always a integer